# Prove that for any $\kappa$ > 0 and $\tau$ there is an helix with such numbers as curvature and torsion respectively

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

i'm trying this problem, but the approaches i find are a little bit tedious. First, i wrote the parametric equation of a helix, and the i used it to find the curvature and the torsion according to the well-known formulas for those numbers without the arc length parametrization. I find those and for me will be suffice to show that those functions are surjective. The other approach is using Frenet-Serret formulas but this is indeed more tedious than the former. Is there an intuitive way to figure out this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you know that for a helix parametrized as $(r\sin t,r\cos t, ct)$, you have
$$
\kappa = \frac{r}{r^2+c^2}\\
\tau = \frac{c}{r^2+c^2}
$$
All we need to do is show that one can solve for $c,r$ as functions of $\kappa,\tau$ given the above simultaneous equations.

One way to do so is to go through a sort of change of variables.  Define
$$
\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{c}{r}\right)\\
\rho=\sqrt{c^2+r^2}
$$
Knowing that this change is invertible, we see that our original set of equations is rendered as
$$
\kappa = \frac{\cos\theta}{\rho}\\
\tau = \frac{\sin\theta}{\rho}
$$
Solving this, we have
$$
\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{\tau}{\kappa}\right)\\
\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau^2+\kappa^2}}
$$

---

In retrospect, the substitution was entirely unnecessary.  Starting with the system
$$
\kappa = \frac{r}{r^2+c^2}\\
\tau = \frac{c}{r^2+c^2}
$$
We divide the two equations to find
$$
\frac{\kappa}{\tau}=\frac{r}{c}
$$
And add the squares to find
$$
\kappa^2+\tau^2=\frac{1}{(r^2+c^2)^2}
$$
That is, we have the system
$$
r=c\frac{\kappa}{\tau}\\
r^2+c^2=\frac1{\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}}
$$
Which can be solved directly via substitution.

Comment: Uhh, thank you very much, i was missing the change of variables, is there any book you can recommend me on that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have one to recommend; that was simply the first thing that occurred to me when I saw the problem. Here's a nice free [textbook on differential geometry](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) by Shiffrin at UGA.